# get rid of deleted files when running git status

Tags: git

When running `git status` It shows a long list of deleted files in the not staged area.  How do you stop the deleted files from showing up in the unstaged area?

The list of deleted files are from a version feature that we do not use anymore.

Comment: add and commit the deletion

Comment: Should I commit them or stash them, it doesn't make sense to commit?

Comment: if the files are in the repo, then the repo needs to know they are gone.  So yes you need to commit the deletion.

Comment: Have you tried `git add -u` or `git rm` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How do you stop the deleted files from showing up in the unstaged area?

If you want to stop them from showing up in the unstaged area, then you need to tell Git that you are not using them anymore

```sh
rm oldfile
git add oldfile
git commit -m 'removed old file'
```

or better yet

```sh
git rm oldfile
git commit -m 'removed old file'
```